# mail function return true but not receiving email

Tags: php, function, email

I am trying to send an email using `php` `mail()` function. Its returns true but not sending mail and showing following.

The description for Event ID 2 from source `PHP-7.2.2` cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

I am using `Windows server`

```
<?php
$to      = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: myemail1@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: myemail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

The script should send an email to `myemail@gmail.com`

Comment: Does PHP work at all? Try: `<?php echo 'hello, I work!';` How do you know the email was not send? Checking whether it arrived is not a reliable method (when using GMail).

Comment: Could you please post dump results?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware
Yes PHP is working fine. I used my gmail ID as receiver side.

Comment: @Jaymin
Thank you for your reply. dump results following

bool(true)

Comment: The most likely problem, apart from the message you showed, is that GMail is blocking the email.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware
gmail not blocking. When I use SMTP its sending emails. The problem is with php mail() function. **I am using laragon 4.0.12**

Comment: Are you trying to do this on Linux based server or Windows machine? Have you checked how the SMTP server is set up in your system?

Comment: When you are pretending that you are sending the email `From: myemail1@gmail.com`, then it can very well make a difference, whether you do that using SMTP with proper authentication, or just using PHP `mail`. If you use SMTP credentials to authenticate with Google’s mail servers - then they think this mail is probably genuine. If you _don’t_ do that, then Google has no way of knowing if the actual “owner” of that mail address wanted to send this mail - of if it was just some spammer.

Comment: You're probably using SMTP in the PHP code in your question. So saying "When I use SMTP" does not convey any information. You need to be more specific, or provide other prove why GMail is certainly not blocking your email. Better try, for instance, the mailbox of your ISP, or any other mailbox you own.

Answer (score 0):

Check your SPAM section in email.

- List item

Comment: Thank you for reply, but there is no email in span as well. after hitting php script its returning true but at server side in windows application logs showing the message I mentioned. **I am using laragon 4.0.12**